# How can I group radio together and still pass them through $_POST as an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, radio-button

**Short Version:**
I know how to pass input values as an array as well as how to delineate between different groups of radio buttons, but I'm not sure how to do it together because I use the `name` property to do both.

**Long Version:**
I want to pass a bunch of selections to a PHP backend. Using basic HTML, a group of inputs can be passed as a single array. I do this with the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choices[]">
```

This is good because I can simply go down the list of `choices` and deal with whatever is in the array instead of checking for a myriad of different names of inputs that were possibly selected.

We also use basic HTML to group radio buttons together. So we can have a group of radio buttons for "Male/Female" as well as "Old Member/New Member" and not have them conflict (meaning, you can only choose either *either* male or female as well as *either* new/old member…the page doesn't force a single choice out of all 4 of those). I do this with the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex">Female
<input type="radio" name="membership">Old Member
<input type="radio" name="membership">New Member
```

So my issue is, how do I do both at once? I need to have separate 'groups' of radio buttons, but still want to pass everything as an array, but the problem is I use the `name` attribute for both! If I name it the array-name, I can't differentiate between the radio-groups. If I differentiate, I lose the array…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the approach I ended up using was to look through $_POST for arrays and then merge them. (Obviously, this only works if you know that the only arrays in $_POST are of the type you need…). This is, roughly, my PHP:

```
    $firstElem = true;
    foreach ($_POST as $element){           
        if( is_array($element) ){
            if($firstElem){
                $firstElem = false;
                $members = $element;
            }else{
                $members = array_merge($members, $element);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set array in action page,

in PHP

```
<?php
    $join = array($_POST['sex'],$_POST['membership']);
?>
```

And you can process based on above array

Comment: It's an idea, but the thing is that the amount of inputs and groups of inputs aren't known before. They are generated dynamically based on database information….